# Android inflate list for MultiAutoCompleteTextview (MultiAutocompleteTextview being inside popup window)

Tags: android, dialog, popupwindow, layout-inflater, multiautocompletetextview

In my application I have inflate my custom view using popupwindow.

Now inside that there is one AutoCompleteTextview which gives suggestions.

Now the issue is that whenever I start typing text inside the AutoCompleteTextView the application crashes.

Error log:-

```
Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@1c6ea57 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

The issue is comming here:-

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder vh;
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());    // ISSUE
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chips_adapter,parent, false);   // ISSUE
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            view.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        vh.tv.setText(suggestions.get(position).getTitle());

        return view;
    }
```

I think error is about inflating a layout on top of another inflated layout.

Comment: pass  the context of your activity to the adapter and use the same context object.

Comment: @SripadRaj Tried using mainactivity context

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class :

Create constructor with parameter of context.

Example : (consider class name is AdapterClass)

```
Class AdapterClass {
   LayoutInflater inflater;
   private Context context;

   public AdapterClass(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
   }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder vh;
        View view = convertView;
        if (inflater == null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chips_adapter,parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            view.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        vh.tv.setText(suggestions.get(position).getTitle());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Note:- When you call AdapterClass don't forgot to initialize constructor with Context as a parameter.

Comment: In adapter initialization I am using my mainActivity context. But its showing this error

Comment: Have passed MainActivity.this inside the constructor?

Comment: Earlier I used this above code(as mentioned by you) but due to same error I tried using parent.getContext() as context.

Comment: It will be helpful if you share your mainactivity code